# On Bluemix - handling volume for container group instances

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, volumes

When i create a container group with 2 desired instances with a command containing the volume specification as follows:

```
> ... -v log_vol:/opt/ibm/logs --env
> LOG_LOCATIONS=/opt/ibm/logs/messages.log,/opt/ibm/logs/debug.log,/opt/ibm/logs/trace.log
> -e TRACE_LEVEL=*~info -e MAX_LOG_FILES=5 -e MAX_LOG_FILE_SIZE=20 ...
```

In this case each individual running-container-instance of the group will have a similar directory `/opt/ibm/logs/` to store logs.

When the application within the individual container instance generates logs, the log data is lost as it is mounted to a shared volume called `log_vol`. The logs get replaced on every new entry.

- Can someone suggest me on how to handle it?
- Are there any ways that we can attach a volume specification post container instance creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it's best to think of the volume as something similar to a shared network drive, with the separate containers running on different hosts. If the processes are assuming they're the only one writing to the file, and caching/overwriting on each write, this will be the result.

Perhaps instead have the containers/programs write to something like `/opt/ibm/logs/messages.$HOSTNAME.log` so that the assumption they own their own logfile is correct?  Or similarly, have the container create for itself `/opt/ibm/logs/$HOSTNAME/` on boot, and then write to `messages/debug/trace.log` under there?

Comment: Yea. This is the approach I have already implemented. Thanks Nate.